# Why dotnet fsi exits without error message in docker container?

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget, f#-interactive

I have a Docker image that works fine on my laptop and when run as a step in a GitHub action. But when I run the image on my server, it fails.

I have been able to reproduce the issue with these simple steps:

1. `docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0`
2. `dotnet fsi`
3. `#r "nuget: Npgsql";;`

That works fine on my laptop. But fails on the server (without an error message.) On the server, after typing `#r "nuget: Npgsql"`, it sits there for a minute and then exits the FSI, returning to the bash prompt.

**Laptop: Windows 10, Docker version 20.10.11** SUCCEEDS

```
C:\> docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
root@5737a66dc73e:/# dotnet fsi

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.0.0 for F# 6.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> #r "nuget: Npgsql";;
[Loading /tmp/nuget/2308--189d6772-0c33-4179-b170-f6bddfd16985/Project.fsproj.fsx]
namespace FSI_0002.Project

> open Npgsql;;
>
```

**Server: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Docker version 20.10.12 (ssh in as root)** FAILS

```
root@server021:/# docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
root@0ff2e4143ca0:/# dotnet fsi

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.0.0 for F# 6.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> #r "nuget: Npgsql";;
root@0ff2e4143ca0:/#
```

**Edit 1**

Does the server-hosted container's F# Interactive have HTTPS GET access to nuget.org? Yes.

```
root@server021:~# docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
root@e0a4050b9505:/# dotnet fsi

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.0.0 for F# 6.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> let client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();;
val client: System.Net.Http.HttpClient

> let response = client.GetAsync("https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/atom.xml").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;;
val response: string =
  "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xmlns="http://www"+[64481 chars]

>
```

I was also able to get valid responses from `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Npgsql/6.0.2` and `https://globalcdn.nuget.org/packages/npgsql.6.0.2.nupkg` using the same technique.

**Edit 2**

Can the problem be reproduced using the older `WebClient` API instead of the newer `HttpClient`? No, WebClient also has no connectivity problems within the F# Interactive.

```
root@server021:~# docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
root@f8a9b61e2991:/# dotnet fsi

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.0.0 for F# 6.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> let client = new System.Net.WebClient();;

  let client = new System.Net.WebClient();;
  -----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/stdin(1,18): warning FS0044: This construct is deprecated. WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.

val client: System.Net.WebClient = System.Net.WebClient

> client.DownloadFile("https://globalcdn.nuget.org/packages/npgsql.6.0.2.nupkg", "npgsql.6.0.2.nupkg");;
val it: unit = ()

> System.IO.FileInfo("./npgsql.6.0.2.nupkg").Length;;
val it: int64 = 2359331L

>
```

---

Any ideas why the image behaves differently on my server?

Comment: Could it be that there is limited network connectivity on the server? Can you try connecting to Nuget from there?

Comment: Good question, @FyodorSoikin. I have edited the post to answer that.

Comment: Maybe there is a subtle network configuration that `HttpClient` handles better than whatever technique FSI.EXE is using to do the `#r "nuget: Npgsql"`? IP4 vs IP6?

Comment: On your Windows machine, are you targeting Linux containers or Windows?

Comment: @MattThalman I believe I am targeting Linux containers. If I right-click on the Docker Desktop icon, I see a menu item that says "Switch to Windows containers..."

Comment: It's the exact same image in both cases @MattThalman

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin - It's the exact same "tag", not necessarily the exact same "image". It's a multi-arch tag so it's dynamic as to what image you'll actually get. Use it when targeting Windows containers and you'll get a Windows image. Use it when targeting Linux and you'll get a Debian image.

Answer (score 0):

The server was **running out of RAM memory**.

There was a server-side log message that stated, "Out of memory: Killed process... (dotnet)..."

I had originally configured the server to have 512MB RAM (presumably to save money.) After increasing that to 2GB, my FSX script runs successfully.

*Thank you to the commenters who helped me rule out other possibilities!*